# can never vs. never can

Tags: modal-verbs, can-modal

Is there any difference between 2 sentences:

1. Steve **can never** find time for us. He needs to be more respectful.
2. Steve **never can** find time for us. He needs to be more respectful.

If there is, please explain the meaning. Thank you.

Comment: Where did the sentences come from? What do you think the difference might be?

Comment: idk my friend, trying to figure out the difference. Seems like 'never can' might convey physical impossibility or smth like tha. But it's not suitable to the context.

Comment: Both are possible. They mean the same. The first is more natural.

Comment: Contrary to the other responses, I (a British English speaker) would probably distinguish between the two in that I'd say that although 'can never' is more common and more natural in most contexts, 'never can', can be used in certain cases to place emphasis on the 'can'. The example that comes to mind is when negating someone else's positive assertion, e.g. "I can't work it out!" might be met with a derogatory "You never _can_ work it out[, can you?]", with the stress as well as the word order emphasising the person's distinct inability to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible.

We usually put **never** after the auxiliary verbs or the modals.

Steve can **never** find time for us.

We can put **never** before the auxiliary verbs/modals to emphasize that two statements are connected.

Steve is always busy. He **never** can find time for us.

Answer (score 0):

They can mean the same, or the second one can be said with a sarcastic or frustrated tone, with stress on "can".